# Database Paging in Android

Tags: android, json, pagination

I want to get the data from a JSON URL. It contains 22 fields and it has above 6000 rows. I want to parse this JSON data and store it in an SQLite database.

I know the basics of JSON but when I use it I get an "out of memory" error.
After a lots of R&D and googling I found that I have to use GSON for Heavy URL, but I'm not familiar with it.

Can I implement paging in JSON? In other words, can I do something like getting partial data from JSON and storing it into a database and then request certain data and store it into a database, continuing the process until the full JSON file is parsed?

Answer (score 0):

You must implement pagination mechanism on server side (the one, that serves you JSON data) and pass range parameters as part of the URL you mentioned.

Comment: ok. can I implement the structure that "get partial data from json and store into db then get agin partial data."

Comment: Yes, this is what I said exactly. But you must do it on **server** side, not client. But it's not "structure", it's piece of code basically.

Comment: But the same URL works fine on iPhone. I dont know how ? but its not the question. My question is what should I do from Andorid side

Comment: You can go the hard way and receive JSON data as ordinary string, and then compose proper-sized JSON objects yourself, but is it worth it?

Comment: Means there is no method or way to handle situation form Android side

Answer (score 0):

If I knew I was going to have lot of rows/data, then I would run some simple SQL call to determine the size of the data. Then break up the original JSON within Android to deal with the data in smaller chunks, committing after each segment. So in your example, you know that you have 6000+ rows - store that in memory in Android as an int, then call 1000 rows at a time.

Some code after further queries:

```
    String locationCountPath = "http://mywebserver/countAllMD5UserLocations";
    try {
        //My method to return a count of locations
        int locCount = MyJSONUtilities.countAllUsersLocations(
                locationCountPath, MyJSONUtilities.writeUserDetailsJSON(
                        username.toUpperCase(), password));
        // Compare new count with count on phone
        if (countLocs != locCount && locCount > 0) {
            try {
                // Grab the new set of locations
                askToSyncLocations();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So, if you replace the askToSyncLocations() method with your own way of handling your 6000+ rows in a loop as batched of 1000 at a time, it should not encounter any memory problems?

Comment: It really depends on how your data are organised, the code is too specific to put here. As I say above, can you work out in advance how many rows your primary SQL (calling a web service from android) returns? I have example code, but need to know you understand what I'm getting at first.